# Wildcard or asterisk (*) vs named or selective import es6 javascript

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, wildcard, es6-modules

Just wondering which one is the best way to use import:

```
import * as Foo from './foo';
```

VS:

```
import { bar, bar2, bar3 } from './foo';
```

In terms of efficiency, say for example, I'm using webpack for bundling all the JavaScript files. Will the first one actually importing everything even though I'm not using them in the main code?

Some references that I can find are:

In [Airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--no-wildcard), they are recommending no wildcard so there will always be default import object, and [this](https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using an ES6 import to load specific names faster than importing a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45735534/1048572)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use webpack with the dead code elimination provided by the new uglify, or rollupjs with tree-shaking, then the unused imports will be stripped.

I partially agree with the airbnb styleguide to not to use wildcard imports, although javascripts wildcard imports do not suffer from the same diseases as for example pythons or javas wildcard imports, namely it does not pollute the scope with variable names defined in other modules (you can only access them by `moduleB.foo`, not `foo` when using `import * as moduleB from ...`).

About the article on testing: I kind of understand the concerns, but I see nothing that cannot be solved there. You can mock the imports themselves with some custom module loader (a custom amd module loader is literally 15 lines of code), so you dont have to mess with the local scope of the tested module.

Comment: if I `import * as Foo from './foo'`, and I use only `Foo.bar`, will `Foo.bar2` and `Foo.bar3` be eliminated as dead code?

Comment: @bsapaka Yes, if `Foo.bar2` and `Foo.bar3` are not used at all.

Comment: Where can I read more about this? For example official docs or github issue threads.

Answer (score 37):

Concerning this part of the question :

> Will the first one actually importing everything even though I'm not using them in the main code?

Here's how it gets compiled with Babel 6.26:

### Named

```
import { bar, bar2, bar3 } from './foo';
```

... becomes ...

```
'use strict';

var _foo = require('./foo');
```

---

### Wildcard

```
import * as Foo from './foo';
```

... becomes ...

```
'use strict';

var _foo = require('./foo');

var Foo = _interopRequireWildcard(_foo);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { 
    if (obj && obj.__esModule) { 
        return obj;
    } else {
        var newObj = {}; 
        if (obj != null) { 
            for (var key in obj) { 
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
                    newObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
        newObj.default = obj; 
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

In both cases the whole file is imported through `require`.

With wildcards imports, an `_interopRequireWildcard` function is defined and used to assign all exports to the namespace variable.

It's worth noting that compiled code will only contain a single `_interopRequireWildcard` definition, and one call to `require` and `_interopRequireWildcard` for each import.

Ultimately, the use of wildcard imports will involve a bit more processing at run-time and cause a slight increase in size for the compiled js.

Comment: Would be great to see if this holds true for webpack 4 with its tree-shaking feature

Comment: The overhead is in babel, there is no overhead if you use rollupjs.

Answer (score 12):

Since, with a modern WebPack setup, the two will generate the same compiled/transpiled JS, the real value in named imports is how much more expressive it is. By naming your imports you are telling any one that opens the file which functions from a module you are going to use. An example of where this can be helpful is when writing tests, if mocking is necessary, you have an explicit list of imports to mock.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @Tamas.
If you require the full access to all exports in the target file, then you can use the `import * as Foo from './foo';` 
or 
`import foo from './foo':`

but if you need to use specific function or const then better avoid "import *" and be explicit what you needs to do.