# Is re-exporting modules harmful for tree-shaking?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, tree-shaking

I've come into an argument with my co-workers for which we can't seem to find an answer from any official source (MDN, webpack documentation, ...). My research [hasn't yielded much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077164/es6-export-from-import) either. There seems to be doubt [even when it comes to importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051588/wildcard-or-asterisk-vs-named-or-selective-import-es6-javascript) as well.

Our setup is Webpack, Babel, and a typical React / Redux app. Take this example:

```js
export * from './actions';
export * from './selectors';
export * from './reducer';

export { default } from './reducer';
```

This allows me to separate a Redux module into logical sections, making the code easier to read and maintain.

However, it is believed by some of my co-workers that `export * from` may, in fact, harm `webpack`'s tree-shaking capabilities, by tricking it into believing an export is used when it is in fact just being re-exported.

So my question is, are there any facts proving or disproving this?

Comment: Why don't you just set up a dummy project and try it? I realize that's not as authoritative as actual documentation from the rollup team, but it ain't nuthin.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues ... Seriously, with open source stuff sometimes the best place to ask is at the repo...

Comment: @Bergi All of those relate to importing. I'm specifically asking about re-exporting using `export * from './module'` which is a different thing.

Comment: @pbondoer Ooops, you're right, I totally confused the syntax with a namespace import where the tree-shaking optimisation is less trivial.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A link to an index page (that is guaranteed to change over time) was the last thing I needed to read.

Comment: @RomainVincent What are you on about? Read the remainder of the comment: "the best place to ***ask*** is at the repo" not the best place to read. Also, this question was already answered quite well by Bergi; do you just click all URLs on a web page or something?

Answer (score 19):

> It is believed that `export * from` may harm webpack's tree-shaking capabilities, by tricking it into believing an export is used when it is in fact just being re-exported.

No, import/export declarations don't do anything but set up an alias to the exported variable, they do not count as a "use". Given their semantics, they are tracked specially by any bundler and will not adversely affect tree-shaking.

Not even a properly done renamed alias will break that:

```
export { X as Y } from '…';
```

```
import { X as Y } from '…';
export { Y }
```

```
import { X } from '…';
export { X as Y }
```

but usage in a statement would count as usage and break (non-sophisticated) optimisations:

```
import { X } from '…';
export const Y = X; // avoid!
```

> So my question is, are there any facts proving or disproving this?

You can just try it out and see it work.