# explicit import versus * sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, npm

What's the point of doing this

```
import * as copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';
```

versus

```
import { someMethod } from 'copy-to-clipboard';
```

Does it affect performance or bundle size? I prefer the 2nd one, it looks cleaner.

Comment: They've got different meanings, one is importing an entire module's contents while the other is importing a single object or value. So does it affect performance? Surely, if the module is enormous.

Comment: There is a pretty good explanation available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051588/wildcard-or-asterisk-vs-named-or-selective-import-es6-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the second form allows bundlers like Webpack to optimize your bundle size using a process known as 'tree shaking'.

> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. import and export. The name and concept have been popularized by the ES2015 module bundler rollup.

Taken from https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Let's say you have a library module like this:

```js
// my-module.js

export const foo = function () { ... };
export const bar = function () { ... };
export const baz = function () { ... };
```

Then, if you use `foo()` in `file.js` as follows, Webpack will recognize that you do not need `bar()` and `baz()` and not emit them in the bundle, reducing the number of bytes sent over the network which in turn can speed up loading of your website.

```js
import { foo } from 'my-module';

foo();
```

Comment: Typo here it should be `import { foo } from 'my-module';`

Comment: so use * to import should be avoided? why so many people use it then?

Comment: If you are going to use all exported objects, then there is no disadvantage to using a wildcard import. Many people use it because the syntax is similar to Java and Python.

Comment: ok, named import is much better, it's also easier to test. avoid * at all cost.